# About the heroku, how to disable SSL verification, error message "WARNING: Unable to verify SSL certificate for api.heroku.com"

Tags: heroku

everyone,
first of all, i have googled yet for this question, and took a ticket in official website,
but still solve this problem,
looking the error message, please,

```
~$ heroku keys:add
Uploading ssh public key /home/my_dir_name/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: example@email.com
Password: 
WARNING: Unable to verify SSL certificate for api.heroku.com
To disable SSL verification, run with HEROKU_SSL_VERIFY=disable
```

I have append the "HEROKU_SSL_VERIFY=disable" to ~/.bashrc, but it not works.
My version of heroku is 2.3.6, 
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the older heroku gem.

First uninstall the newer gem:

```
 gem uninstall heroku
```

Then install an older gem that seems to work:

```
gem install heroku -v "<2.0.0"
```